# How can I access resources of the library

Tags: android, jar, android-asynctask, android-resources, android-library

I am trying to create an Android library which provides AsyncTask operations. I created my AsyncTask as below. However, I don't know how to access library's resources. The context field is set by the activity who uses that library. I used to access the resources by calling getActivity().getResources(). But this AsyncTask's context comes from the project that uses it and I don't know how to access the library's resources. How can I achieve that?

```
public class CheckBalanceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Context mContext;
String json;
JSONObject jsonObject,jsonObjResult;
JSONArray jsonArray;
String message,balance;
ProgressDialog progress;
    public CheckBalanceAsyncTask (Context context){
         mContext = context;
         //progress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//          progress.setCancelable(false);
//          progress.setMessage("please wait");//getString(R.string.pleasewait));
//          progress.setTitle("waiting");//getString(R.string.loading));
//          progress.setIcon(R.drawable.ic);
//          progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
//          progress.setProgress(0);
//          progress.setMax(100);
//          progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String aliasNo = "";

            PackageInfo pinfo = null;
            try {
                pinfo = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String versionName = pinfo.versionName;

            String cardServiceUrl = "blabla";
            Log.e("LOGGGGG", cardServiceUrl);

            try {
                json = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(cardServiceUrl);
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser",
                            "Error creating json object" + e.toString());
                }
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cardlist");

                jsonObjResult = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");

                message = jsonObjResult.get("message").toString();

                Log.e("MESSAGE", "" + message);

                JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                balance = row.optString("balance");

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.e("json", "doInBackground2");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            //progress.dismiss();

            try {
                if (jsonObjResult.get("message").toString()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, balance+" TL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Library means??FAcebook sdk and etc

Comment: You want the context of library project in library project? If that's it then don't use the mContext which was provided by the project which uses the library, just use your own context by using this or getContext()

Comment: I am calling only this AsynTask class in the library for my project and I can't access the library's resources from AsynTask class. getContext and this is not defined in AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 1):

Ressources are automatically merged with the main application then, no need to do something specific to access string, drawable, layout, etc...
getActivity().getResources() will work fine.

Comment: for example, I need to call getString(R.string.server);  in asynctask. However, I don't have access to library's context. With mContext I can only access the project's context who uses this library. How can I access the library's own context in AsyncTask?

Comment: @FigenGüngör You should send context to constructor of your AsyncTask

Comment: @FigenGüngör With the context of the application, you have access to library ressources. When the application is compile, R.string.server will be merged in ressources of the application. Then, with the context of the application, you have access to this string.